# Approximate every monotonic increasing function $f$ uniformly by a sequence $(f_n)_n$ of step functions, s.t. $f_{n+1}-f_n$ is monotonous increasing?

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence, monotone-functions, step-function

Is it possible to approximate every monotonic increasing function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ uniformly by a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of step functions on $[0,1]$, s.t. for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $f_{n+1}-f_n$ is monotonous increasing? Step functions denounces linear combinations of indicator functions of all intervals $[0,y],[0,y[, y \in \mathbb{R}$

It seems easy, but I'm starting to think, it's not possible at all and it seems to me, that's the case, because like for the identity I need $\mathcal{O}(\lceil\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rceil)$ points to make for an error $<\varepsilon$ and the infinite sum of all the countably many corrections made before any given point, has to converge.

Comment: Is $f$ supposed to be continuous ?

Comment: No. I should clarify what I mean by step functions.

Comment: But I don't even think it works for continuous functions.

Comment: What is wrong with the question?

Comment: can you give a hint to a construction method? Because that would be helpful to the question in the general case, considering how there can only be countably many jump discontinuities.

Comment: This is a lot trickier, than it seems to be. I tried several constructions. First, I tried to use quantiles of negative powers of 2 and somehow substract a penalty to the later points in the grid, but that did not really work out, because I had no Idea how to continue that pattern in a way, that does not only ever add points in the beginning.

Comment: Another Construction I tried, was to always add certain functions, which are in part negative,  but that did not really work out either.

Comment: The former construction not being sufficient lead me to believe, that it has to do with the fact, that I need linearly much points to make that error small.

Comment: anyways without the requirement of the differences being monotonous increasing, it is possible to approximate any monotonous function on a compact interval by step functions. This can be done by taking quantiles, which I refer here.

Comment: Ok, I wrote an answer in the continuous case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous and non constant, this is impossible.

Indeed, if $f_{n+1}-f_n$ is increasing for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then for all $p>q$, $f_p-f_q$ is increasing. Letting $p$ tend to $+\infty$, you get that $f-f_q$ must be increasing for all $q$. In particular, $f_q$ must be decreasing (otherwise you would get a contradiction at an increasing step of $f_q$, by continuity of $f$). But if $f$ is increasing and non constant, it cannot be the limit of decreasing functions.

Comment: such a bummer, but yes. Furthermore is impossible to even have any sequence of step functions s.t. $f-f_q$ is increasing, by that same argument.